# Check if Redshift Undergoing Maintenance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, boto3

Is there an aws cli or boto3 function for determining if Redshift is undergoing maintenance and not-accessible?

For example we have loads failing when the database is undergoing an upgrade or vacuum jobs are running.  It would be nice to check for this rather than see failing jobs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are a superuser then you can run SVV_VACUUM_PROGRESS.

```
select * from svv_vacuum_progress;
```

Regarding maintenance, you need to schedule around [maintenance windows](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-clusters.html#rs-maintenance-windows). Failing that, you have to rerun aborted transactions.  To see which transactions were aborted, you can run:

```
select query, elapsed, label
from svl_qlog where aborted=1;
```